# При вставке ссылки на сайт добавляется изображение

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Вставляю ссылку на сайт, сайт сделан на Wordpress, к примеру в записи на фейсбук или в диалоге в скайпе и ссылка переделывается в Title, Description и изображение. Скрин ниже

http://lostandfoundthenovel.com/

Можете попробовать вставить в новую запись на фейсбук чтоб понять о чем я.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что являяется этим изображением ? Почему из всех изображений на сайте выбирается именно это и как его поменять ? Логотип добавлен на сайт, но скрыт в CSS

Comment: при вставке таких ссылок в ВК, например, можно пролистать изображения, которые есть на странице, то есть там приводятся все изображения, по порядку. Возможно с некоторой фильтрацией по размерам, если таковые указаны в атрибутах `img`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Что являяется этим изображением ? Почему из всех изображений на сайте
>   выбирается именно это и как его поменять ?

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://lostandfoundthenovel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/amazonFirst.png" />`

[Матчасть](http://ogp.me/)

Если тема не поддерживает установку данного изображения (многие могут назначать для для каждой страницы), то поменять можно напр, с пом. плагинов.